# How to pass a method from one component to another and use it onclick in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So in my App.vue component, I have two other components being rendered, and what I want to achieve is this, when the user clicks on the play button, animateRing() method from the component ProgressRing should be used, my code looks the following:

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ProgressRing>
        <PlayButton
          @click="animateRing(), active = !active"
          :class="{active: active}"
        />
    </ProgressRing>
  </div>
</template>
```

PlayButton.vue

```
<template>
  <button class="play-button" @click="$emit('click')">
    ...
    some irrelevant code here
    ...
  </button>
</template>
```

ProgressRing.vue

```
<template> 
...some code...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    animateRing(){
      console.log('I'm animated');
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I can't seem to figure out the right way to do it. What is the best way to make the method to work in the App component? I'm relatively new to Vue and didn't really figure it out yet.

Comment: Try to use a scoped slot in ProgressRing to pass its context to PlayButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you can accomplish this:

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ProgressRing ref="progressRing">
        <PlayButton
          @click="animateRing(), active = !active"
          :class="{active: active}"
        />
    </ProgressRing>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    animateRing(){
      this.$refs.progressRing.animateRing()
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I'm curious about the reason for `PlayButton` being a child of `ProgressRing`, but not defined in ProgressRing.vue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it worked for me. And answering your question, I'm just trying to make the stuff work somehow and I guess I'm still not really sure how it all should look like in the application, so thank you for the hint :)

Comment: I think it'd be cleaner to move it into `ProgressRing.vue`, that way `App.vue` doesn't need the animateRing method. But I don't consider myself an expert with Vue.

Comment: I just started learning it like a couple of days ago, so I think you might be right and it would really look nicer if I move it

Comment: Good stuff. Best of luck to you!